# Вопросы использования побитовых операторов

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть код который проверяет что буквы в строке не повторяются:

```
public class isUniqueChars {
    public boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
        int checker = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            checker |= (1 << val));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Как это работает, помогите пожалуйста разобраться. В частности что значит запись:

1. `1 << val` что значат эти стрелочки в данном контексте?
2. `checker |= (...` вот это `|=` что-то похожее на или равно, ноже не понятно как работает.
3. `int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';` а что к чарам можно арифметические операторы применять или это что-то другое?

Объясните пожалуйста как это прочесть и понять?

Comment: Набросок на ответ: int это набор 32 бит. Если на входе маленькие латинские буквы (26 штук), то одного int достаточно. `x & (1 << i)` проверяет установлен ли i-ый бит в x, а `x |= (1 << i)` устанавливает i-ый бит (означает, что i-ая буква встретилась).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дополню ответы описанием самого алгоритма, приведенного здесь.

На самом деле это просто слегка заоптимизированная работа с массивом флагов (булевых значений), только вместо массива выступает целое число, состоящее из 32 бит, каждый из которых выступает в роли такого флага.

Как было написано в других ответах, java позволяет простую конвертацию char и int друг в друга: char представляет собой символ UTF-16, т.е. он кодируется двумя байтами, и полностью помещается в int (в него помещается даже surrogate pair, состоящая из двух символов UTF-16, поэтому часть методов использует int там, где мог бы быть char). char таким образом может представлять 2^16 разных символов, но этот алгоритм учитывает только символы латинского алфавита - а их всего 26 (52, считая оба возможных регистра, но чуть ниже будет описано, как они сливаются). В ASCII-таблице, на основе которой существуют почти все кодировки (в том числе, UTF-16), эти символы идут подряд:

```
64 @
65 A
66 B
...
96 `
97 a
98 b
99 c
...
```

Поэтому чтобы вычислить положение символа N в нижнем регистре внутри алфавита, можно вычесть из его позиции позицию первого символа (`'a'`), что и происходит в вышеприведенном методе:

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

В случае, если charAt вернет латинский символ в верхнем регистре, результат будет ровно на 32 меньше - как показано выше, два регистра латинского алфавита в таблице отстоят ровно на 32 позиции:

```
'a' - 'a' = 0
'c' - 'a' = 2
'C' - 'a' = -30
('C' - 'a') % 32 = 2
```

При делении с остатком на 32 эти значения схлопнутся (результат для 'C' и 'c' будет одинаковым), что позволяет не учитывать регистр.

Все это приводит к тому, что алгоритм выяснения, состоит ли слово из латинского алфавита исключительно из уникальных символов можно привести к следующему:

- Создать массив флагов вхождения для каждого символа
- При первом вхождении символа выставлять соответствующий флаг в "присутствует"
- При втором вхождении (т.е. при обнаружении соответствующего флага в состоянии "присутствует") возвращать false - найден первый повторяющий символ
- При завершении исследования вернуть true, т.к. совпадений не было найдено

метод при этом выглядел бы следующим образом:

```
public class isUniqueChars {
    public boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
        boolean flags[] = new boolean[32];
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int index = (str.charAt(i) - 'a') % 32;
            if (flags[index]) {
                return false;
            }
            flags[index] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Однако общее количество возможных значений составляет 32, что позволяет оптимизировать метод и использовать вместо флагов обычный int. В int 32 бита, каждый из которых можно использовать в качестве boolean - если бит выставлен, то это true, иначе это false. Именно так и использует int автор метода. Для этого используется операция битового сдвига влево, которая просто представит число в виде набор бит и сдвинет его влево на указанное количество позиций, как будто сдвинет позицию, с которого этот набор читается:

```
0b0111 << 2 
  = сдвинуть биты на две позиции влево, первые два бита поставить в конец
  = 0b1101 // последние два бита сдвинулись на две позиции влево, первые два бита встали в конец
```

Операция `1 << val` создает int с одним выставленным битом, позиция которого определяется с помощью val, и т.к. в int вмещается 32 бита, результат равен `val % 32` (сдвиг на 32 бита влево вернет int в исходное положение):

```
shift = 'c' - 'a' = 2
carrier = 1 << shift = 1 << 2 = 0b000...001 << 2 = 0b000...0100
```

Таким образом наличие символа 'a' обозначает выставленный в единицу самый правый бит, 'c' - третий справа бит и так далее. В качестве состояния (массива флагов) автор использует переменную checker, в которую складывает соответствующие биты:

```
checker = 0 = 0b000...000
...
checker |= 1 << val = checker | (1 << val)
```

операция битового или (`|`) выставит в 1 все биты, которые выставлены хотя бы в одном операнде:

```
0b000...010 | 0b000...001 = 0b000...011
```

Поэтому эта операция эквивалента `flags[index] = true` в примере выше (за тем исключением, что отсчет ведется справа, а не слева). Операция `(checker & (1 << val)) > 0` проверяет наличие этого флага: битовое и (`&`) выставит в 1 все биты, которые есть в обоих операндах

```
0b000...110 & 0b000...011 = 0b000...010 // сохранился только второй бит справа, который присутствует в обоих операндах
```

т.к. правый операнд представляет собой int c одним выставленным битом, результат будет не равен нулю, если такой бит присутствует и будет равен нулю, если бит отсутствует. Как было описано выше, бит может присутствовать только в том случае, если символ, соответствующий позиции бита, уже встречался, поэтому наличие этого бита говорит о том, что символ встречается повторно, и входная строка имеет повторы.

Таким образом, данный метод:

- Использует биты int32 как массив булевых значений (флагов)
- При анализе символа находит соответствующий ему флаг (бит), и если он выставлен в 1, возвращает false
- При анализе символа выставляет соответствующий флаг (бит) в 1
- При окончании анализа строки возвращает true, т.к. совпадения не были найдены.
- Все это абсолютно идентично использованию массива boolean, но немного более экономно по памяти и скорее всего примерно так же эффективно по производительности.

Comment: мда мне видать надо основы подтянуть... А не подскажите как вообще эта тема называется ну я про биты просто я на уровне битов вообще никогда не рассматривал процессы. Побитовые операции это когда понятно что такое биты а вот как эту тему поднять? Пару тройку ключевых слов не подскажите, так чтобы с основ пробежаться...

Comment: @Павел все это называется bitwise operations и в общем нет какого-то специального раздела по этим вещам - просто есть некоторый набор операций, с которым процессору легко работать, поэтому с ними можно легко оптимизировать. Я сам до конца эту кухню на лету не схватываю, и со многими вещами сейчас сижу с блокнотом, расписывая конкретные операции и различные варианты. Если хотите залезть совсем глубоко, то можно почитать pcasm - это учебный материал по ассемблеру, и там рассматриваются многие базовые операция типа сдвига или кодирования знаковых чисел.

Answer (score 5):

```
1 << val
```

Битовый сдвиг влево. Если не ошибаюсь, в данном случае сдвигает единицу на val позиций. А вообще, как правильно заметили в комментарии, сдвигает все биты.
Например val = 3, тогда
единица в битовом представлении (для краткости показаны только последние 8 из 32 бит) `00000001` превращается в `00001000`. Или 8 в десятичной системе.

```
checker |= (1 << val)
```

Это тоже самое, что

```
checker = checker | (1 << val)
```

Т.е. аналог таким операторам как `+=` `-=` для битовых операций. Много таких операторов (`+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `%=` `&=` `^=` `|=` `<<=` `>>=` `>>>=`) чтобы немного облегчить задачу набора текста программы.

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a'
```

Ну да, java позволяет выполнять кое-какие арифметические действия с char-ами. Почему бы, собственно говоря, и нет?
В данном случае очевидно вычисляется порядковый номер (начиная с нуля) символа в алфавите abcd...
Например если str.charAt(i) окажется равным d, то val получится равным 3.

Ещё можно прибавлять или вычитать числа из char, получая таким нехитрым образом другой char, отстоящий от заданного на заданное количество позиций (`char a = 'c' - 2; char d = 'a' + 3;`) Только char в данном случае должен быть задан константой. Прибавить число к переменной char не получится.

Comment: все верно, только оператор "<<" сдвигает не единицу, а все биты (из текста ответа можно подумать так). тип `char` - просто шестнадцатибитное  беззнаковое целое число (код символа unicode), поэтому с ним допустимы **все** арифметические операции, доступные для целых чисел (в некоторых случаях понадобится явное приведение к типу).

Comment: @pavlofff Да, Вы совершенно правы. Сдвигает все биты. Просто хотел написать "в данном случае", но не написал, а потом забыл. Ща поправлю.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

> а что к чарам можно арифметические операторы применять или это что-то
>   другое?

---

Компилятор Java неявно преобразует char в int, в случае когда нужно число, т.к. тип char является подмножеством типа int. Поэтому к char можно применять всё то же что и к int.

Comment: откуда информация про неявное приведение char к int?

Comment: Artem Konovalov я что-то написал неверно?

Comment: Может и верно, мне просто интересно, откуда вы про это узнали, потому что я про такое не слышал.

Comment: Судя по [спеке](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3), char поддерживается самой jvm, поэтому компилировать его в int большого смысла нет. Но будет неудивительно, если он хранится как 32битное слово и в некоторых местах jvm работает с ним как с интом.